# Solve the equation $x^{2n} + 1 = 0.$ Use these solutions to find a factorization of $x^{2n} + 1$ with real coefficients.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I am asked to solve the equation $x^{2n} + 1 = 0,$ and to use these solutions to find a factorization of $x^{2n} + 1$ with real coefficients. I am given the hint that pairing factors arising from complex conjugate pairs of roots is essential.

After some manipulation, I can find that $x = e^{i\pi(2k+1)/2n} \; \forall \; k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Then when $k=0$, it's pretty clear that $x=i^{1/n},$ but I'm not sure what to do for other $k$.

For example, when $k = 1$, I get $x = e^{3i\pi/2n}$ and I am unsure how I can simplify that further. I can put it in polar form, but I don't how to go from there to rectangular because of the $n$ in the denominator of $\theta.$

Comment: For each root $\omega$ of $x^{2n+1}$, $(x-\omega)(x-\bar\omega)=\cdots$

Comment: Just write $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ where your $\theta$ has a denominator of $2n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $e^{i\pi(2k+1))/2n}$ and $e^{i\pi(2(2n-k-1)+1))/2n}$ are complex conjugate.

This means that

$$(x-e^{i\pi(2k+1))/2n})(x-e^{i\pi(2(2n-k-1)+1))/2n}) \in \mathbb R[x]$$

Do the multiplication above, and you'll see that you get a nice explicit real quadratic.

Comment: When I do the multiplication I get $$x^2 + xe^{-ki\pi/n}e^{-i\pi/2n}-xe^{ki\pi/n}e^{i\pi/2n}-1.$$ I don't understand where I can take it from there.

Comment: @user110524 Last term should be $+1$. And write the exponentials in trigonometric form, and you are done..

Comment: I very much appreciate your helping me with this, and I don't mean to question you, but are you sure the last term should be $-1$? Fully expanded, I get $$x^2 - 2i\sin{\frac{2k\pi+\pi}{2n}}-1.$$ I've checked my answer with _Mathematica_ and that gives the same result.

Comment: I believe the formula for a complex conjugate of $e^{i \pi (2k + 1)/2n}$ is $e^{i \pi (2(n-k+1) + 1)/2n}.$

Comment: @user110524 $e^{i \pi (2k + 1)/2n}e^{i \pi (2(n-k+1) + 1)/2n}=e^{i \pi (2k+1+2(n-k+1) + 1)/2n}=e^{i \pi (2k+1+2n-2k+2 + 1)/2n}=e^{i \pi (2n+4)/2n}\neq 1$ in general.

Comment: @user110524 And check your signs, when you expand you have $$(x-e^{i\pi(2k+1))/2n})(x-e^{i\pi(2(n-k-1)+1))/2n})=x^2-e^{i\pi(2k+1))/2n}x-e^{i\pi(2(n-k-1)+1))/2n}x+e^{i\pi(2k+1))/2n}e^{i\pi(2(n-k-1)+1))/2n}$$ From your answer it looks like you got the last two signs wrong.

Comment: Yeah, my last comment only worked in the $n = 2$ case. But the conjugate of $e^{i\pi(2k+1)/2n}$ is not $e^{i\pi(2(n-k-1)+1)/2n}$. If you multiply or add those you do not get a real. The conjugate is simply $e^{-i\pi(2k+1)/2n}$.

Comment: @user110524 You are right, I made a typo, the conjugate is $$e^{i\pi(2(2n-k-1)+1))/2n}$$ which is the same as you said..... I fixed my answer, sorry again for the typo.

Comment: No worries. I needed to exercise my algebra anyway. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
x^{2n}+1 = \prod_{k=1}^n \Big(x^2+2\cos\big(\!\tfrac{k\pi}{n}\!\big)x+1\Big).
$$

Comment: Thank you! But I believe the second term in the product function should have an $x$.

Comment: @user110524: I made the correction.